# wso2 identity server migration : SQL ERROR when migration TOTP secret keys

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to migrate wso2 identity server from 5.10 to 5.11. The migration process breaks and throws an sql exception while migrating TOTP secret keys (error stack below).

Any insights on what the problem might be ?

Thanks in advance .

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-06-08 17:50:21,524] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl} - Migration process was stopped. org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.migrate.MigrationClientException: Error while migrating TOTP secret keys.
        at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.util.TotpSecretUtil.migrateTotpSecretKeys(TotpSecretUtil.java:85)
        at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.v5110.migrator.EncryptionUserFlowMigrator.migrateTotpSecretKey(EncryptionUserFlowMigrator.java:74)
        at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.v5110.migrator.EncryptionUserFlowMigrator.migrate(EncryptionUserFlowMigrator.java:58)
        at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.VersionMigration.migrate(VersionMigration.java:52)
        at o
        at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.util.TotpSecretUtil.migrateWithJDBCIdentityStore(TotpSecretUtil.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.util.TotpSecretUtil.migrateTotpSecretKeys(TotpSecretUtil.java:79)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 UPDATE IDN_IDENTITY_USER_DATA SET DATA_VALUE='eyJjIjoiZlKamFYxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxQ==' WHERE TENANT_ID='-1234'
AND USER_NAME='w.SHAKESPEARE1@preprod.test' AND DATA_KEY='http://wso2.org/claims/identity/secretkey' was aborted: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying
  Indice : No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position : 64  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:148)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:824)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeBatch(PgPreparedStatement.java:1538)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.util.IdentityClaimDAO.updateNewTotpSecrets(IdentityClaimDAO.java:118)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying
  Indice : No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position : 64
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:821)
        ... 43 more
```